# Problemas obteniendo una imagen desde la carpeta public en una ruta. Laravel.

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

en una de las tablas que cree de la base de datos hay un campo de tipo file.

El archivo (imagen) se almacena de forma correcta en la base de datos. De la siguiente forma:

```
    if($request->file('imagen')){  //condicion de si existe la peticion                             
 $publicacion->imagen=Storage::disk('public')->put('image',$request->file('imagen'));                                                                                 
$publicacion->fill(['file'=>asset($publicacion->imagen)])->save(); //almacena la imagen la carpeta public en una carpeta nueva llamada image. 
   }
```

Funcion en el controlador para llamar los datos de la base de datos y mostrar en una vista:
 public function articulo($id)
    {

```
    $publicaciones=Publicacione::where('id',$id)->get();

    return view('articulo')->with('publicaciones',$publicaciones); //la vista se llama articulo y la ruta articulos. 
}
```

Vista:

```
<img  src="{{$publicacione->imagen}}" alt="">
```

La imagen no se muestra, al inspeccionar el código fuente se muestra la ruta de la imagen:

image/7kReFxMpxgucU3Vac5hVqCqdUFRcgtMcQ7sJ3v3T.png
pero al clickear se abre la siguiente ruta:

http://localhost/cymma/articulo/image/7kReFxMpxgucU3Vac5hVqCqdUFRcgtMcQ7sJ3v3T.png

PD: El problema creo que se genera es por el prefijo articulo de la ruta, pero no se como proceder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con

```
<img  src="{{url('/'.$publicacione->imagen)}}" alt="">
```

ó

```
{{ HTML::image($publicacione->imagen, 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ha sido muy valiosa.